# How to use tensorflow 2.3 with GPU in windows 10

Tags: gpu

I created a virtual environment and installed TensorFlow 2.3 without anaconda, like this:
[image]

And I installed NVIDIA driver, CUDA, cudnn
[image]

[image]
But GPU still doesn't work in tf....
I do not know what mistake I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change CUDA 11.0 to CUDA 10.1
and cudnn to 7.6